# How do i recieve message from my arduino to my webpage as a text using javascript MQTT

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mqtt

I have been trying to find out how to i receive incoming message from my arduino to populate the data in my webpage.
It will be nice if anybody would know!

```html
$(function () {
    var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://busHelper:busHelper@broker.shiftr.io', {
        clientId: 'SmartBus'
    });

    client.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('client has connected!');
    });

    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        console.log('new message:', topic, message.toString());

    });


    client.subscribe('/UserStatus');
    client.subscribe('/lat');
    client.subscribe('/lang');
    client.subscribe('/busSelection');
```

Comment: Post a clear consistent question *and* title if you want to get answers. The title is the first thing anyone sees. `regNumber CHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (regNumber like '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]')` will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could use websockets for the live update, try socket.io
https://socket.io/

Configire socket.io listener in backend that it will act as a bridge. In the on message function event socket.io will pass that message to frontend

Answer (score 0):

To use either the Paho Javascript MQTT or the MQTT.js clients from with the browser, your broker needs to support MQTT over websockets.

This also means your URL needs to start with `ws://` not `mqtt://` to signify the protocol to use.